# Command php -v on command prompt generates interactive shell terminal

Tags: php, wamp

I just reinstalled a new windows(10) system on my PC:
And Then I installed tools that I need for my workspace. When I installed wampserver, that's where the problem happens: it is nice and well installed but when I tried to run "php -v" command, in C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8. 0.13, on my command prompt;

My command prompt open another terminal with writing on it interactive shell (basically weird stuff), while the command supposed to show the version of php in the bin directory of the wampserver.

[image: interactive shell execution after "php -v"]

I have already searched everywhere and asked the different search engine but it did not give any tangible solution to solve the problem.
If there is someone who has already faced similar problem, I will be very happy to try the solution he found.

Comment: You are going to have to try and show us all this "WIERD STUFF" to give us a clue.

Comment: Wouldn't you run `php.exe -v` on Windows? Does WAMP create a shortcut/link named `php`?

Comment: @brombeer No, but the exe lives in `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.0.13\php.exe` WAMPServer can have multiple versions of PHP installed and thats how it copes with them all

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for clearing that up, never developed in Windows/WAMP

Comment: What do you want to acheive? Which kind of "error" are you facing? Also, please remove the parts from your question that are not relevant - or explain how that "anti-virus 360" is related to your problem

Comment: @RiggsFolly, https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k1z9.png I just imported the interactive shell image. Infact, I don't know if it's weird or not the fact that I run the command php -v on command prompt and open the interactive shell of the terminal. Cordially

Comment: are you sure you didnt do a `>php -a` to load the interactive shell :)

Comment: I didn't even know the existence of the >php -a command before today

Comment: Hi @Nico Haase, the problem what when i execute command php -v on cmd or just php, It opens an interactive shell terminal.
And about anti-virus 360, it's a friend's experience. And I tried the way he fixed the problem, unfortunately it didn't work with me. I hope you understand better now the problem I faced.